# How to trigger glue Job with Airflow dynamic tasks and run them sequentially

Tags: python, airflow, aws-glue, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to understand and use dynamic task mapping in airflow. I have this code:

```
import json
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import boto3
import urllib3
from airflow.decorators import task, task_group
from airflow.models import DAG
import hvac
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue import GlueJobOperator

default_args = {

}

DAG_ID = "dag-id"

with DAG(dag_id=DAG_ID,
         schedule=None,
         description="testing",
         default_args=default_args,
         start_date=datetime(2023, 8, 21),
         catchup=False) as dag:

    def get_credentials():
        # code to get aws creds

        return region_name, access_key, secret_key, session_token

    @task
    def processing():
        # this just gets some s3_keys by calling a lambda
        region_name, access_key, secret_key, session_token = get_credentials()
        session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
                                aws_session_token=session_token, region_name=region_name)

        lambda_client = session.client('lambda')

        response = lambda_client.invoke(
            FunctionName='lambda_name',
            InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        )

        response_payload = json.loads(response['Payload'].read().decode('utf-8'))

        body = response_payload['body']

        print(type(body))
        return body.strip('][').split(', ')

    @task
    def run_glue_ingestion(s3_key):
        GlueJobOperator(
                task_id=f"test-job-{DAG_ID}",
                job_name="glue-job",
                job_desc=f"Glue test",
                script_location="s3_path",
                retries=0,
                region_name="us-east-1",
                iam_role_name="role_name",
                run_job_kwargs={
                    "SecurityConfiguration": "sec_config"
                },
                verbose=True,
                script_args={
                    "--s3_path": f"s3_path/{s3_key}",
                    "--environment": "dev",
                },
                num_of_dpus=2,
                aws_conn_id='aws-personal-conn'
            )

    values = processing()
    glue_ingestion_task = run_glue_ingestion.expand(s3_key=values)

    values >> glue_ingestion_task
```

This generates the following
[image: UI image]

It has 3 run_glue_ingestion mapped tasks and they all succeed. However, they all return None and nothing gets triggered in Glue.

However, when I annotate run_glue_ingestion with @task_group() instead of @task. It gives me this:
[image]
Doing it this way, the glue jobs are getting triggered (they fail due to some issues with the script). However, this seem to add another layer to the tasks. Is this grouping necessary and what is wrong with the first method? Why is GlueJobOperator not triggering anything without using @task_group()?

Also, at the moment all the mapped tasks in run_glue_ingestion execute concurrently. How can I execute these dynamically mapped tasks sequentially, i.e. wait for one GlueJobOperator job to finish before starting another one?

Comment: You'll want to start by moving the `GlueJobOperator` outside of the `@task` decorated function. Instead, you'll want to do something like `glue_ingestion_task = GlueJobOperator(...)`

Comment: I'm still a bit confused how I would pass s3_key to each task. Would it be something like:
glue_ingestion_task = GlueJobOperator.partial(
                task_id=f"test-job-{DAG_ID}",
                job_name="glue-job",
                ...
            ).expand(script_args={
            "--s3_path": f"s3://polarlake-all-trp-dev-iceberg-ingest-landing/{values}",
            ...
        }

I'm a bit confused how to pass different key to each created task.

Comment: No. It was fine as it was. passing `.expand(s3_key=values)` will automatically create a mapped task instance, and pass one item in `values` to the `s3_key` parameter of each mapped task instance.